# String to JSON to BytesIO

Tags: python, json, bytesio

I have some working code:

```py
with io.BytesIO() as byteObj:
    for fileRow in workingBlob.download_as_string().splitlines():
        byteObj.write(_to_bytes(json.dumps(iterate(json.loads(fileRow)))+'\n',encoding="utf-8"))
```

But this feels messy/ a lot of conversion.  Am new to Python and am wondering if there is a smarter way to do?

Code is already working- just want to learn to see quicker/ better/ more efficient ways of doing this (code was built with lots of help from Googling/ stack overflow)

Comment: what data ```workingBlob``` holds?

Comment: A google cloud storage bucket blob?

Comment: Yes iterate loops through the JSON object and modifies specific values